# Create a LINQ query comparing arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, linq

I'm very new to LINQ and I'm searching to filter an SQL view which has a column called 'Readers' containing several group names separated by '#' (es. "Administrators#HR Group#Employees Group").
Having a list of user's groups, I need to extract all the records where Readers  contains at least one of the user's groups.
In other words, the user must see only those records belonging to him.

I found this solution, but I think it's extremely inefficient:

```
private List<vwFax>getmyFaxes(List<string> myGroups)
{
    var myFax = db.vwFax.AsQueryable();
    var res = db.vwFax.AsQueryable();
    List<vwFax> outRes= new List<vwFax>();

    foreach (string elem in myGroups)
    {
        res = (from a in myFax
                where a.Readers.Contains(elem)
                select a); 
        if(res.Count() > 0)
        {
            outRes.AddRange(res);
        }               
    }
    return outRes.ToList();
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Maybe `(from a in myFax where a.Readers.Any(r => myGroups.Contains(r)) select a).ToList()`

Comment: `db.vwFax.AsQueryable().Where(x=> myGroups.Any(y=> x.Contains(y)).ToList();` you can also create a stored proc instead of LINQ.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with `if(res.Count() > 0){outRes.AddRange(res);}` because you are executing the SQL query `myGroups.Count` time, instead of executing one big query. Using LINQ queries above you will execute only one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are saying in the following query is: For each item in `myFax` take it only if that `item.Readers` contains `Any` (at least 1) of the items in `myGroups`

```
outRes = db.myFax.Where(item => myGroups.Any(grp => item.Readers.Contains(grp)));
```

and in query-syntax:

```
outRes = from item in db.myFax
         where myGroups.Any(grp => item.Readers.Contains(grp))
         select item;
```